# How do I programmatically dump JMX data?

Tags: java, logging, jmx, jconsole

I want to be able to log all JMX data accessible via jconsole. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I'm building a form of logging of the system, and I want to create intervaled data viewable with some tool similar to jconsole.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[java.lang.management.ManagementFactory](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html)  gives you access to JMX data.

i.g.

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memPoolBeans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
for (MemoryPoolMXBean mpb : memPoolBeans) {
    System.out.println("Memory Pool: " + mpb.getName());
}
```

Some samples are available at SO query: [java]+managementfactory

A good read: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09196/index.html

For full implementation connecting to a remote VM:

```
Map<String,String[]> env = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
env.put( JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, new String[]{"user","pass"} );
JMXServiceURL address = new JMXServiceURL("service:rmi:///jndi/rmi://host:port/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(address,env);
MBeanServerConnection mbs = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

//get all mbeans
Set<ObjectInstance> beans = mbs.queryMBeans(null,null);

for( ObjectInstance instance : beans )
{
    MBeanInfo info = mbs.getMBeanInfo( instance.getObjectName() );
}
```

From the info, you can query object names and attributes as desired.

Comment: This works, but is there an easy way to get all values from all objectnames? Right now, it seems as if I have to get na MBeanServerConnection, then query each value individually with mbs.getAttributes(..). Is there a better way?

Comment: Okay, I can get all the ObjectNames with queryMBeans, but I'm still unable to automatically get all attributes.

Comment: :P. Now, I can query all attributes, but the way you do it is extraordinarily circuitous. I'm going to edit your answer and make it a little more complete, then accept it.

Comment: fantastic code snippets and infomation.  The link to the IBM page is also fantastic.  Spent ages trying to access a custom MBean and your last snippet does it for me, nice one thanks +1

Answer (score 5):

I used this [command line JMX client](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/) as a starting point when I wanted to do the same thing.

Comment: It looks like I really want 10.4, for the "Attributes" command, but the link ont he page is broken. Any ideas where I might find a mirror?

Comment: I think that is the version I have. You can get it here: http://drop.io/jmxclient